# How to send SMS to the contact list one by one adding their First Name in message

Tags: swift, ios8, sms, message, addressbook

Here I'm retrieving all contacts from my address book and calling  function `prepareSMSmessage()`, this function internally calling `MFMessageComposeViewController`

```
func listAllContacts(addressBook : ABAddressBookRef)
    {
        var contactRef: ABRecordRef! = ABPersonCreate()?.takeUnretainedValue() as ABRecordRef!
        var count:Int32 = 0
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, { (granted : Bool, error: CFError!) -> Void in if granted == true
        {
            /* Get all the people in the address book */
            let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(
                addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
            count = 1
            for person: ABRecordRef in allPeople{
                var contactName : String = ""
                if  var firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString {
                    println("FIRST NAME: \(firstName)")
                    contactName = firstName
                }
                if  var firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString {
                    println("LAST NAME: \(firstName)")
                    contactName = firstName
                }
                var phones:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)
                for index in 0..<countOfPhones{
                    let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as String
                    println("Phone: \(phone)")
                    self.prepareSMSmessage(contactName ,cell_number: phone)

                }

            }
            }
        })

    }
```

**Here is my  prepareSMSmessage()**

```
func prepareSMSmessage(firstName :String,cell_number:String)
    {

    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Dear \(firstName) \n\n  How are you ? Please attend my kid birth day party today at 7PM.‏\n\n Veeru";
    println(messageVC.body)

    messageVC.recipients = [cell_number]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion:nil)

    //self.presentViewController(messageVC,animated: true)

}

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.value) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
        println("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
        println("Message failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
        println("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```